# jquery buffer/queue for effects? Or to tell if an effect is in process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, effects

I have a click event that checks to see if a form is correct i.e. filled out details.. and then i call a function that does this

```
$('#message_text').html(text);
$('#message_system').fadeIn("slow");
$('#message_system').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 5000)
                    .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
```

All works ok, as long as i wait .. if i double click the button twice for example that it stops displaying ...

I presume if it is hidden hide() then fadeIn() will automatically show it?

Anyone got any experience with this ??

What i probably would like to do is on the second click then disgard current effects and redisplay new messaage

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but have you looked at the [stop()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop#clearQueuegotoEnd) method.
You can skip straight to the end of any current animations by calling `$('#message_system').stop(true, true)` before beginning again.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ! $(this).is(':animated') ) {
    // Do the animation...
}
```